# Unknown 302 redirect happening in wordpress site, redirecting https to http

Tags: wordpress

I'm running a wordpress site in IIS 10 on windows server and I'm trying to switch to HTTPS but when I do (using a plugin or manually changing the config file) I get a redirect loop. I did a redirect check and it turns out there's a 302 redirect happening that redirects https to http.  Is there any plugins or ways I can check for what's causing the 302 redirect? I am using woocommerce as well as a genesis child theme. I'm at a loss as to what is causing the 302 redirect, any help on what to look for is greatly appreciated.

Comment: EDIT: of course 10 minutes after posting this I found the solution. Woocommerce had the force http after checkout option applied. So it was the culprit.

Comment: You may answer your own question to help others: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this, the answer for me was woocommerce had the "force HTTP after checkout" option checked. This caused a redirect for every page other than the checkout.