# WooCommerce 302 redirect to homepage after checkout is finished

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, redirect, http-status-code-302

I have an unusual error I don't seem able to fix myself ... I have a WordPress website, with WooCommerce as shop-part of the site. Today I noticed, that after I make an order, (Select product > Add to cart > Proceed to Checkout ) after I fulfill the order-form, choose the payment and click "FINISH ORDER" ... I don't see the "Thank you for your order", with order details, but instead, I get automatically redirected to homepage via 302 redirection.

- I tried to switch themes back to TwentySeventeen - not working.
- I reverted .htaccess back to "original" WordPress one - not working.
- I deleted quite a lot of the plugins website normaly uses - not working.
- I removed whole CDN integration - not working.

For some unknown reason, "thank-you-page" redirects via 302 redirection back to homepage.

The order is processed and customers get e-mail notification properly, it's just that  thank you page (where order details should be seen) isn't loaded.

I already checked [this Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160950/unknown-302-redirect-happening-in-wordpress-site-redirecting-https-to-http) - but I don't have the "Force the HTTP after checkout" option within WooCommerce Dashboard.

You can see the "Network" part of Dev Tools here:

- Image 1: https://prnt.sc/lnbqcs
- Image 2: https://prnt.sc/lnbq5o
- Image 3: https://prnt.sc/lnbqqj

This is the System report:

- WC Version: 3.5.1
- Log Directory Writable: ✔
- WP Version: 4.9.8
- WP Multisite: –
- WP Memory Limit: 1 GB
- WP Debug Mode: –
- WP Cron: –
- Language: sl_SI
- External object cache: –

Server Environment

- Server Info: Apache
- PHP Version: 7.0.32
- PHP Post Max Size: 64 MB
- PHP Time Limit: 900
- PHP Max Input Vars: 20000
- cURL Version: 7.60.0
- OpenSSL/1.0.2k
- SUHOSIN Installed: –
- MySQL Version: 10.0.37-MariaDB
- Max Upload Size: 64 MB
- Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
- fsockopen/cURL: ✔

Please try to help me ... I'm stuck here for the past 3 hrs and didn't figure it out (today) ... Much appreciated!

Thank you,

T.